# Seaborn histogram with horizontal coloring

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a several histograms with `plt.subplots()` like this:

```
chart_len  = 15
chart_height = 25

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(weight_classes),figsize=(chart_len,chart_height))

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid",font_scale=2.5)
colors = sns.color_palette('GnBu_d',len(weight_classes)+1)
 
for i, wc in enumerate(activity_wc):
        data = activity_wc[wc]
        bins = [i for i in range(0,data['total_strikes_attempted'].max(),5)]
        
        sns.histplot(data,x='total_strikes_attempted', bins=bins, ax=axs[i], kde=True, stat='probability', color=colors[-(i+2)])
```

This retrieves this image:
[histogram subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toy7P.png)

What I'd like though would be for the **bars** to use the palette, so they would change colors horizontally. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `ax.containers[0]` contains all the histogram bars. You can loop through them and set individual colors. The norm (mapping the x-values to the range 0-1) can be based on the first and last bin boundaries.

Basically, the code would look like:

```py
ax = sns.histplot(...)
norm = plt.Normalize(bins[0], bins[-1])
cmap = sns.color_palette('GnBu_d', as_cmap=True) # use 'GnBu_r_d' for the reversed map
for bar in ax.containers[0]:
    bar.set_color(cmap(norm(bar.get_x())))
```

Supposing `activity_wc` is the result of `activity.groupby('weight_class')`, the plot can be obtained more directly from the original dataframe. `sns.displot` with `row='weight_class'` would take care of the grouping and creating a grid of subplots. Note that the `figsize` would be controlled by `height=` with the height of an individual subplot, and `aspect=` with the aspect ratio of one subplot (width divided by height).

Here is an example starting from dummy data. Note that the bins are starting just smaller than zero to avoid rounding errors, and that one bin edge is added to make sure the highest value falls into the last bin. (Use `sns.displot(..., facet_kws={'sharex':False})` to have x-tick labels for each subplot.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

weight_classes = ['Flyweight', 'Bantamweight', 'Featherweight', 'Lightweight', 'Welterweight',
                  'Middleweight', 'Light Heavyweight', 'Heavyweight']
activity = pd.DataFrame({'weight_class': np.random.choice(weight_classes, 1000),
                         'total_strikes_attempted': np.concatenate([np.random.binomial(120, p, 100)
                                                                    for p in np.linspace(0.2, 0.9, 10)])})
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid", font_scale=0.8)

bins = np.arange(-0.00001, max(activity['total_strikes_attempted']) + 5, 5)
g = sns.displot(data=activity, x='total_strikes_attempted',
                row='weight_class', row_order=weight_classes,
                kind='hist', stat='probability', kde=True, palette='GnBu_d',
                height=1.6, aspect=3)
norm = plt.Normalize(bins[0], bins[-1])
cmap = sns.color_palette('GnBu_d', as_cmap=True) # use 'GnBu_r_d' for the reversed map
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.margins(x=0) # less white space left and right
    for bar in ax.containers[0]:
        bar.set_color(cmap(norm(bar.get_x())))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: displot with bar colors changed]

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you.